# How to add an image overlay to clickable button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a heathered image to hex color buttons for T-Shirts I'm selling. They're plain colors right now, but for some of the shirts, I want them to have an overlay showing the pattern. How can I add an image to specific buttons (since not all shirts are heathered) and set an opacity for that image? Here's my code right now. I found a good example of how I want it to look online for you to see what I mean. You can check it out here: [Heathered Color Swatch Overlay Example](https://cottonbureau.com/products/vintage-seattle-helmet#/1400006/tee-men-standard-tee-premium-heather-tri-blend-s).

Here's my code I currently have:

```
$colors: ( 
  'color-Navy'                  #2D2F3C,
  'color-Ash'                   #EEF0F2,
  'color-Black'                 #060606,
  'color-White'                 #F6F6F6,
  'color-Charcoal'              #59545A,
);

@each $color in $colors {
 $colorName: nth($color, 1);
 $bgColor:   nth($color, 2);

#ProductSelect-option-#{$colorName} + label {
  background-color: $bgColor;
  color: $bgColor;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#ProductSelect-option-#{$colorName}:checked + label {
  border-color: #555;
  border-width: 3px;
 }
}
```

Comment: That's not CSS .

Comment: @j08691 assume Levi are using something like LESS.

Comment: Levi, I assume you mean the `button` below the product (in the demo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you want an image to overlay the colored background of each button that will convey whether a shirt is heathered.

If I got all of that right I think what you're looking for is the CSS `background-image` property, but you'll need to choose an image format that supports transparency like `.gif` or `.png`

Then open your shirt-shaped image in an image editor and use the eraser tool to scrub the edges or whatever until it looks sufficiently heathered for your liking and then add it to your project and set it as the `background-image` of each button.

[This](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) page may be able to help.